# Mapping XML to incoming paramaters

Tags: c#, xml, object, input, request

I have a piece of XML data that is being sent of to an API, at the moment the XML data contains hard coded values. I want to make this dynamic. Essential when a user sends a POST request to my API using a particular method and defining certain inputs i want to map these inputs to my EXTERNAL XML template and then send this request of to a third party API.

Currently everything is working using hard coded values and i retrieve a response from the third party API as an XML string which i am serialising into an object and then displaying to the user.

Would i need to create another object for the request as well as the response? i am unsure on how to do this.

C# METHOD:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public Provisioning LLUCancel()
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/Provisioning/LLUCancel.xml");
        doc.Load(path);

        string xml = doc.InnerXml;
        string _url = "https://webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LLUProvisioningService/LLUPublicProvisioningWSV19.asmx";
        string _action = "https://webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LLUPublicProvisioningWS/SendCommand";

        var soapResult = WebService.ApiRequest(_url, _action, xml);

        XmlDocument xmlToFormat = new XmlDocument();
        xmlToFormat.LoadXml(soapResult);

        string Outerxml = xmlToFormat.FirstChild.NextSibling.FirstChild.FirstChild.LastChild.OuterXml;

        //Remove all namespaces
        var xmlToBeStripped = XElement.Parse(Outerxml);
        string finalXml = XmlFormatter.stripNS(xmlToBeStripped).ToString();

        Provisioning result;

        // Deserialises xlm into an object 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Provisioning));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(finalXml))
        {
            result = (Provisioning)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

XML:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <SendCommand xmlns="https://webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LLUPublicProvisioningWS">
      <request>
        <UserCredentials>
          <Username>username</Username>
          <Password>PASS</Password>
          <AgentID>794</AgentID>
        </UserCredentials>
        <Command xsi:type="LLUCancelCommand">
          <ResellerReference>TTB Test</ResellerReference>
          <ResellerAccountReference>XML Example</ResellerAccountReference>
          <CancellingRID>BVE</CancellingRID>
          <TargetCommandID>114102073</TargetCommandID>
          <Provisioning xsi:type="CLIProvisioningIdentifier">
            <CLI>01514890609</CLI>
          </Provisioning>
          <CancelReason>OrderCancelledByOperator</CancelReason>
        </Command>
      </request>
    </SendCommand>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Currently i am not passing in any parameters but this is the next step/

Comment: Yes you need another object.  The request and response are shown on following webpage : https://webservices.opalonline.co.uk/LLUProvisioningService/LLUPublicProvisioningWSV19.asmx?op=GetCommandDetails

Comment: how would i map it to the external xml file

Comment: You can get the resposne stream and then use xmlToFormat.LoadXml(response stream);